# How to exclude duplicate records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query whose output is like the below:

| ID | Case_When_Output_Column |
| --- | --- |
| Abc123 | Search Performed |
| Abc123 | Other activities Performed |
| EFG456 | Search Performed |
| EFG456 | Other activities Performed |
| PQR999 | Other activities Performed |
| LMN012 | Other activities Performed |

As you can see, we have ID's where search is performed and also "Other activities" are performed.
Eg: Abc123, EFG456

However, I am looking for ID's where only "Other Activities" are performed. (Search should not be performed)
Eg: PQR999, LMN012

How do I frame such a query?

Comment: SQL is a language, SQL-developer is a tool. Oracle is a database. Please add a database tag to your question and also please show us what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function to count the number of rows for each `id` and only return the rows where the count is `1` and `Case_when_output_column = 'Other activities Performed'`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       Case_when_output_column
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  Case_when_output_column = 'Other activities Performed'
AND    cnt = 1
```

If you want any number of `'Other activities Performed'` rows for each `id` then you can count the `DISTINCT` cases:

```sql
SELECT id,
       Case_when_output_column
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT Case_when_output_column) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  Case_when_output_column = 'Other activities Performed'
AND    cnt = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Case_When_Output_Column) AS
SELECT 'Abc123', 'Search Performed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc123', 'Other activities Performed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EFG456', 'Search Performed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EFG456', 'Other activities Performed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PQR999', 'Other activities Performed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LMN012', 'Other activities Performed' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | CASE_WHEN_OUTPUT_COLUMN |
> | --- | --- |
> | LMN012 | Other activities Performed |
> | PQR999 | Other activities Performed |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be82bbf345cc8a71107aa2afdd6bf6f7)*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to only bring back IDs with only one occurrence, or only bring back IDs with "Other activities Performed" in the output column?

If the former, then you can join to a select statement like so

```
select t1.ID, t1.Case_When_Output_Column
from table as t1
join (select ID, count(ID) as vol from table group by ID) as t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t2.vol < 2
```

It the latter, you just need a where clause such as

```
select *
from table where Case_When_Output_Column = 'Other activities Performed'
```